# What brand of laptop should I buy for photo editing?

Tags: photo-editing

I am just beginning to really excel in photography, and am in need of a new laptop. (I have been using a Chromebook but I can't download editing applications that I want.) I want to buy a new laptop, but am not sure which one to buy that will be good for photo editing. I like the Lenovo Yoga 2 11.6" (TouchScreen 2-in-1 Laptop PC - Intel Pentium N3520 / 4GB DDR3L / 500GB HD / HD Webcam / WLAN 802.11b/g/n / Bluetooth 4.0 / Windows 8.1 64-bit). Would you suggest this? Or are there some cons that you feel I should know about?

All suggestions and advice are appreciated! I'd also like to know which applications you would download with which computers. Thank you!!

Comment: Do not get a 2-in-1 expecting it to be useful in tablet form for working on Photos or really anything professional. Sadly, its not at all.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A laptop is not so ideal for photo-editing work as it is computationally demanding work which requires a lot of cooling. This may not be much of a concern if you only do simple photo-editing work, high end photoshop work etc., but for computationally intensive work, e.g. working with huge image stacks, where the computer needs to run for many hours, you may then find that your laptop will throttle down its processing speed after a while while a desktop would have no problems running at full speed.

The more RAM your computer has the better, mine has 8 GB but there are some tasks that it cannot handle in one go even when working on small (e.g. 1000 pixels by 1000 pixels) images. I then need to crop the image into different parts, process them separately and then stitch the parts together.

The more cores your processor has the better, the processing involved in photo-editing is usually highly parallelizable, and if there is idle processing capacity, you can start up different instances of certain programs to work on different pictures simultaneously without that slowing down the entire process. E.g. for image aligning work I often start up 4 instances of the align_image_stack program to get the job done 4 times faster.

The hard drive should be at least 1 TB, and you want to buy external hard disks for backups. I have two external hard drives, one with 1 TB capacity and another one that has 4 TB capacity. The 1 TB external hard drive is for system backups, while the 4 TB is for both system backups and file history back ups. The total backup capacity in use now is about 5 times the size of the used memory on computer's my hard disk.

File history backups are important not just to get your file back in case you need to perform a system  reset, but also to deal with corrupted files. If some image file gets corrupted it will also be backed up, this means that only a file history backup system can give you back the uncorrupted version of the file, simply making copies of everything on your hard disk is not good enough.

The programs I use for photo-editing work are all free of charge:

- [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/)
- [ImageJ](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/)
- [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net)
- [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)
- [dcraw](https://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/dcraw.c)

Most of the work I do is done with ImageJ, there are a large number of plugins available [e.g. here](http://bigwww.epfl.ch/algorithms.html), and it is easy to write your own plugins. The Hugin program is useful for aligning images, it comes with programs such as align_image_stack that are called from within the GUI, but which you can use as a standalone command line program. ImageMagick is a command line program useful can be useful to convert a large number of images to another format, to convert to another colorspace etc. The dcraw program allows you to convert raw files to tiff such that you have full control over the processing. This allows you to e.g. do no processing at all, which yields a tiff file where the gray values of the pixels are exactly as captured by your camera sensor. You can then process this data using your own algorithms.

My experience with my 8 GB, quad core intel i7 processor laptop using the programs listed above, is that the main limitations are due to the computer having to throttle down to prevent overheating. So, a more powerful laptop will not do much good. A desktop will have a better cooling system allowing it to handle hard core photo editing work involving a large number of image files that takes a lot of time, much better.

---

Added to this answer: As pointed out by Michael Clark in the comments, another important thing to consider is that laptop screens will not be able to display the colors in a picture as well as IPS panels can.

Comment: I disagree that 'a laptop is not so ideal'. Laptops come quite powerful today, and there are really poor towers too. It all depends on what laptop (or tower) you get - you need a _powerful_ machine. [mine has 32 GB, an i7-4720HQ, and SSDs, and it is lightning fast with LR an PS)

Comment: @Aganju Yes, they are powerful, but they are not suitable to run at full throttle for a long time (more than, say, ten minutes). My less powerful laptop will throttle down after several minutes (depending on the ambient temperature), it cannot sustain maximum performance for a long time. This is a fundamental problem, a laptop (unless not so powerful) simply cannot cool itself down to sustain maximum effort indefinitely like a desktop can. That problem may not much of a big deal, I can still manage with my laptop, but this is still a relevant limiting factor that one has to take into account.

Comment: To see the difference between a laptop and a desktop, you need to consider a large amount of processing that would require the computer to run for many hours. Then it will become apparent that a quad core 3 GHZ or better laptop hasn't run at maximum throttle for the entire duration. One can argue that doing such things is not typical photo-editing work. But you have to note here that commercial software like Photoshop avoid using algorithms that require massive amounts of computations, so this may give people a false impression of what results can be achieved at what computational expense.

Comment: You are totally missing the most important point of processing on a laptop vs. desktop: the quality of the screen to reproduce a wide color gamut. Most laptop screens do not have near the color gamut that even a low to mid-priced IPS panel can cover.

Comment: @MichaelClark I've added that in my answer. Thing is that being colorblind, my own color gamut isn't all that good.

Answer (score 3):

> I am just beginning to really excel in photography

Good for you! :o)

> which applications

- The obvious choice is Photoshop and Lightroom.
- Or Gimp and some free raw editor.

  Regarding the computer you should take a look at the minimum system requirements: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/system-requirements.html

In general terms I would look for a computer at least with a i5 processor.

There are some sub numbers, for example i5 4xxx or i5 6xxx That indicates the "generation" Look for at least a 4 generation. The newer the generation the better.

A i7 6xxx would be the newest processor up to this date.

Comment: apart from what Rafael has suggested, check the screen resolution and it's color rendering capacity. If screen doesn't render colors properly then what you edit will be slightly different from what you print.